# How to hide options from HTML dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp-tags

I am trying to hide the dropdown select options from an html pop up. When I click close, the popup clears, but the dropdown options still remain on the screen.

Here is my code:

**HTML :**

```
<div id="xyz">
    <select multiple="multiple"   class="dropDown" property="x" >
        <c:forEach items="${aa.ab}" var="ab">
            <option value="${ab.id}">${ab.description}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Button :**

```
<input type="button" onclick="PopupUtility.hidePopupElement(this); closeDropDown();" value="Cancel"/>
```

**JS :**

```
function closeDropDown() {
    var x = document.getElementById('xyz');
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
      x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have tags like this: `<c:forEach>`? What environment is that from?

Comment: I see you are trying to loop through results from a `getElementByID` call. Are there multiple dropdowns on one page which have the same ID?

Comment: @ScottMarcus : user has jsp and is using jstl (jsp standard tag library), it has the c tags

Comment: You do not need the loop in the closeDropDown() function - each ID must be unique so all you need is to apply the display none style to the element with the id (document.getElementById('xyz').style.display = 'none'). If you have more than one element with the specified ID - then you need to change that id to ensure that each id is unique.